# how split data with respect of months?

Tags: pandas, time-series

Hi I have a time series data set. I would like to make a new column for each month.

data:

```
 creationDate            fre      skill
2019-02-15T20:43:29Z      14       A
2019-02-15T21:10:32Z      15       B
2019-03-22T07:14:50Z      41       A
2019-03-22T06:47:41Z      64       B
2019-04-11T09:49:46Z      25       A
2019-04-11T09:49:46Z      29       B
```

output:

```
skill   2019-02     2019-03      2019-04
 A        14           41          25
 B        15           64          29
```

I know I can do it manually like below and make columns (when I have `date1_start` and `date1_end`):

```
dfdate1=data[(data['creationDate'] >= date1_start) & (data['creationDate']<= date1_end)]
```

But since I have many many months, it is not feasible to that this ways for each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with convert datetimes to month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creationDate']).dt.to_period('m')
df = df.pivot('skill','dates','fre')
```

Or to custom strings `YYYY-MM` by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creationDate']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df = df.pivot('skill','dates','fre')
```

EDIT:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

It means there are duplicates, use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with some aggregation, e.g. `sum`, `mean`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='skill',columns='dates',values='fre', aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: what is this error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: TypeError: pivot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aggfunc'

Comment: @elham - It is `pivot_table` instead `pivot`